# How do i convert a JSON string to an array with objects with

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to convert the following string to an array

```
[{id: "1", type: "railroadCrossingSign", latitude: "55.647432", longtitude: "12.187673"}, {id: "2", type: "stationSign", latitude: "55.647444", longtitude: "12.187545"}]
```

Unfortunately an error occurs when I am `JSON.parse()`, probably because of the objects in the string...

How do i convert a **JSON string with objects** to **an array with objects**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want. **Your JSON key value pair must in a string format too.**
Say,

```
var obj = '[{
  "key" : "value"
}]';
```

Finally, when you use:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.name + ", " + obj.age;
```

You get the following results:

> John, 30

Answer (score 5):

`JSON` format requires that your keys also must be wrapped into `""`.

```js
var string = '[{"id": "1", "type": "railroadCrossingSign", "latitude": "55.647432", "longtitude": "12.187673"}, {"id": "2", "type": "stationSign", "latitude": "55.647444", "longtitude": "12.187545"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(string);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- First make sure your JSON should be a valid JSON.
- Object properties should be wrapped into quotes **`""`**.

[image]

- If your `JSON` is already an `JSON Object` then no need to `parse` it again otherwise it will throw an error.

```js
var jsonObj = [{
 "id": "1",
 "type": "railroadCrossingSign",
 "latitude": "55.647432",
 "longtitude": "12.187673"
}, {
 "id": "2",
 "type": "stationSign",
 "latitude": "55.647444",
 "longtitude": "12.187545"
}];

var newObj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);

console.log(newObj); // Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```